# What is the name of this part of an old window?

Tags: repair, windows

I am in the process of restoring old windows. These are original to the house and hence from 1940. Windows have these plastic or metal ventilation plugs, here are two pictures:
[image]

[image]

The problem is some of the windows miss these parts, and I would like to replace some of the older ones. I, however, have no idea what these parts are called. I tried to google some random terms (such as vent plugs for wood windows) but did not find anything.

So, what is the official name of this part? and it is possible to buy a replacement?

Comment: Are you sure they're vent plugs and not pivot points to allow the window to tilt?

Comment: I take it that your windows are single pane, fixed in place (glazed in frame) with no movable sash?

Comment: They look like screen mounts or sash support sockets to me. Wooden windows usually aren't ventilated like that.

Comment: @Duston Yes, these are ventilation plugs, there are holes going outside. These windows have a second insert, which is usually is installed for the winter time (like small inside storm windows) and these plugs are open for the winter to reduce the condensation.

Comment: @Jack Yes, but please see my comment above.

Comment: @isherwood No, these are ventilation plugs. Please see my comment above.

Comment: Any idea how old these windows are? Are they replacements or original?

Comment: @GregNickoloff Now I am pretty sure the windows are replacements (there was a serious tornado in the area around 1956). Also, a neighbor's house from 1968 has exactly the same windows. So my best guess would be that these windows are from late 50th, early 60th. The windows are Andersen .

Comment: @Artem I tried to find replacements, but a lot of it depends on more information about the windows than I have. Andersen has a lot of information on their website--especially in the parts/support section. Have you tried contacting Andersen directly? Maybe send them the pictures and ask what they are and how to get replacements, etc? It could be that they're associated with the storm windows and were "added on" to the existing windows if they aren't Andersen parts.

Comment: @GregNickoloff Yes, this turned out the way to go. I got an exact reference on a different forum. I will post it as an answer myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This item is called "Wood Casement Air Ventilator" and is available through the Andersen web page, here is a link. I did not find any metal replacements, only plastic, but these are exactly the same size.

https://parts.andersenwindows.com/detail_0533008__w_wcasement_sash.html

Comment: You should "accept" your answer....